# When do worksheets get assigned their .CodeName property?

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

So, in the process of my VBA here, I have a sub in my workbook that creates a sheet, and dynamically adds code to that new sheets activate event. It's pretty cool actually. However, I'm running into a problem with the sheets code name, where the new sheet is not assigned a code name when I go to reference it.

The code used to get a reference to the new sheet code module is: `With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(CName).CodeModule`  where CName is the sheets code name.

I get the CName with: `CName = Workbooks(ExcelFormName).Sheets(NewSheetName).CodeName`
Where NewSheetName is a global constant. This always works because this code is executed in the same function as the creation of the sheet, thus the user has not had a chance to rename the sheet.

I found through testing (including hair pulling) that when i created the worksheet: `Set ws = Sheets.Add(, After:=Sheets(Worksheets.count))` the sheet was not assigned a code name unless the vbe window was open.. i used `debug.print "Test " & ws.codename` to confirm that codename was blank - `""` so when I tried to reference the sheet using the code name, i was getting an error. What I found i could do is:

```
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
Application.VBE.MainWindow.WindowState = vbext_ws_Minimize
```

before I create the sheet, to quickly open and minimize the VBE window (I later close it) which i didn't like but it worked. But now I'm running into issues where some users have security settings that dont allow the vbe window to open.

I noticed, just now, If i loop through all of the vbcomponents in my workbook, without even doing any processing like:

```
Dim test As VBComponent
For Each test In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
Next
```

then after that, the worksheet has a code name.. So i'm wondering, what can I do besides loop through the components like that to make sure the new sheet has a code name, and without doing that, when does a worksheet normally get assigned its code name if the VBE window is not open?

### Edit

A picture of the results of your suggestion siddharth:

[image]

You can see, I added your suggestion, I got the error 9, subscript out of range error

### Edit2

```
Dim CName As Variant
CName = Workbooks(ExcelFormName).Sheets(NewSheetName).CodeName
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(CName).CodeModule 
    StartLine = .CreateEventProc("Activate", "worksheet") + 1
    .InsertLines StartLine, "Dim numRows As Long"
    .InsertLines StartLine + 1, "Dim numColumns as long"
    .InsertLines StartLine + 2, "numRows = 0"
    .InsertLines StartLine + 3, "numColumns = 0"

    'mode codez
```

I'm dynamically adding code to the new sheets activate event. I would add it normally but this sheet is deleted when the user closes the book. This particular sheet is not needed all the time, so I don't want it there unless the particular user needs it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a very old problem. To access the codename, use this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets.Add(, After:=Sheets(Worksheets.count))

Msgbox ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).Properties("Codename")
```

However for this code to work, you have to check `Trust access to the VBA-Project Object model`

[image]

Comment: The code that I posted is tried and tested :) but let me wait for your screenshot

Comment: ya man, check it out.. codename is different than sheetname, RIGHT AFTER creation of it... i dont understand myself

Comment: It is working just fine for me and it should for you if you are using `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).Properties("Codename")` right after you create the worksheet.

Comment: Wait there is something wrong with your Excel file. Why do you have Excel icons next to `Sheet, 17 and 18`? Can you close Excel and try my code in a new excel file?

Comment: Seems like some kind of corruption.

Comment: simply create your new file can copy the code across. Do not copy whole sheets across.

Comment: Ya, I'll do that, thanks. Now though, the codename for the new sheet (tested in new file) still isnt assigned untill after all code is finished unless I have the VBE window open, what can i do to force the codename to be assigned before the rest of the code is executed?

Comment: Example, when i do `MsgBox (ws.CodeName)` before doing `Msgbox ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).Properties("Codename")` i still get a blank. Is there any proper way to force this codename designation process without using like debug or msgbox?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However would like to know what exactly are you planning to do with that codename.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. If you want to use `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).Properties("Codename")` then you will have to do it immediately after you create the sheet. BTW Do you want to add code to the newly add sheet?

Comment: Yes I know that siddharth :) What I'm going to do is probably something like: `ws.name = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).Properties("Codename")` this will force the application to designate the sheet its code name. Then the next line I'll go `ws.name = NewSheetName` Thus, the sheet has its proper name, and its code name, and a few lines later when I do `CName = Workbooks(ExcelFormName).Sheets(NewSheetName).CodeName` I'll get the code name for that sheet :) and yes, I am dynamically adding code to the new worksheets activate event, it works good :) do you know a better way though?

Comment: No that's perfect :) I thought your 2nd edit meant that you are getting more errors :) Glad it is all sorted :)

Comment: yeh :D and thanks again for pointing out my corruption issue, that may have had further consequences down the line and I'd have had no idea

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46953/discussion-between-user1759942-and-siddharth-rout)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up for anyone else reading, after creating the worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets.Add(, After:=Sheets(Worksheets.count))
```

use: `ws.name = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).Properties("Codename")`

it should not change the sheets name, as before renaming a new sheet the name is the same as the codename, but it will force the application to designate the codename, rather than wait until after all the code is run.

if executing code like `msgbox ws.codename` without first doing something with `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).Properties("Codename")` then `ws.codename` will be blank